# How to render CSS from code behind

Tags: asp.net, webforms, code-behind

Suppose I have a string which has CSS classes, I have to render it on page load.

My string value is:

```
.Class1 { display: none; } .Class2 { display: none; }
```

Comment: You could have some server control (e.g. [`Literal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol)) on your ASPX page and set its value from within your page's `Load` event handler.

Comment: @UweKeim Thanks for giving the idea, its working perfect ! I think you can write as answer.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Seems like a code smell to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ASPX page, define a [`Literal` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol) like e.g.:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="MyCss" />
```

Then, in the `Load` event handler of your code-behind, set the text like e.g.:

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    MyCss.Text = ".Class1 { display: none; } .Class2 { display: none; }";
}
```

Depending on your usage scenario, you would nest your `Literal` control instance inside other HTML or server controls.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to include the style tag?  "<style type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">" + .....styles....  + "</style>"